# When to set proxyBeanMethods to false in Springs @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When looking at springs autoconfigure [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure) it seems that every auto-configuration class sets `proxyBeanMethods = false`.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false)
public class SomeAutoConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

The javadoc gives a detailed explanation for this particular field:

> *Specify whether {@code @Bean} methods should get proxied in order to enforce
>        bean lifecycle behavior, e.g. to return shared singleton bean instances even
>        in case of direct {@code @Bean} method calls in user code. (...)*
>   *If this is not needed since each of this particular configuration's {@code @Bean}
>        methods is self-contained and designed as a plain factory method for container use,
>        switch this flag to {@code false} in order to avoid CGLIB subclass processing.(...)*

After reading this I'm still confused when it is better setting it to false.

Here are my questions:

- Can someone give a concrete example when this field should be true and explain why?
- Why is this field set to false on the auto-configuration classes?

**Update:**
 Found two issues on github that give some explanation why it is `false` on most auto-configutation classes:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9068
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22461

Comment: If you don't call the methods directly on the configuration class but only reference the beans created by them you can set this to `false`. If you do call the methods you cannot set it to `false`. If you are calling the method, and it isn't proxied, each call will create a new instance of the bean, with a proxy this is intercepted and the same bean will be returned. Not needing to generate a proxy shaves of some startup time

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your explanation! So whenever I expect someone to call the methods from my `@Configuration` class directly this should be left `true`, correct?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=true)
public class SomeConfiguration {
    @Bean
    ServiceA serviceA(){
      return new ServiceA(sharedService());
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceB serviceB(){
      return new ServiceB(sharedService());
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceC sharedService(){
      return new ServiceC();
    }
}
```

Here, the proxyBeanMethods will assure that the 'sharedService' method will be intercepted and its result re-used. If you would follow the normal java logic, when calling serviceA() and serviceB(), there would be two different instances of ServiceC, and when calling sharedService() directly, a third instance would be created. Then proxy interceptor will make sure the actual method is only called once, so only one instance of the shared ServiceC is created, and both ServiceA and ServiceB will get the shared instance.

However proxyBeanMethods=true has a performance cost during startup, especially for libraries with a lot of @ Configuration classes, like spring-boot's internal libraries. See e.g. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9068#issuecomment-461520814 for the impact on Spring WebFlux.
They couldn't change it to false by default, since that would break backwards compatibility. See links in the original question.

You can use different configuration patterns to avoid this, which is probably what auto-configuration classes do.

One way to do this is auto-wiring the service via method parameters instead of nested method calls. It makes less sence in normal Java, but it works in Spring configurations:

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false)
public class SomeSmarterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ServiceC sharedService(){
      return new ServiceC();
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceA serviceA(ServiceC sharedService){
      return new ServiceA(sharedService);
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceB serviceB(ServiceC sharedService){
      return new ServiceB(sharedService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would one turn set `proxyBeanMethods=false`? I.e. would someone *want* to generate a new bean `sharedService` bean for each service? Seems like the idea in spring is to have a single shared service

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi proxyBeanMethods=false is a performance improvement, especially for libraries with a lot of @ Configuration classes, like spring-boot's internal libraries. They couldn't make it a default, since that would break backwards compatibility. See links in the original question.

Comment: Any source / number / ticket regarding the `performance improvement` claims ?

Comment: @DennisC see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9068#issuecomment-461520814 where they tested it with the Spring Boot Webflux example.

Comment: You would want to disable proxying whenever proxying gets in the way. For example, if you want to iterate through all the annotations on a class, a Spring CGLib proxy would report 0 annotations even if it had some.

Comment: Spring recently introduced @AutoConfiguration annotation, which already sets proxyBeanMethods to false: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfiguration.html. This is giving us the conclusion that Spring recommends this setting with auto configuration classes.

Answer (score 0):

Spring introduces proxyBeanMethods in version 5.2.  The default value of proxyBeansMethods is true.  That implies proxy objects will be generated for classes configured with @Configuration by default. In Springboot version 2 and onwards, all AutoConfiguration classes are configured with @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false). This is because the automatic Configuration feature is widely used in SpringBoot. Generating proxy objects will increase the startup time of spring and increase the object memory of the proxy part.  The best practice is to annotate configuration classes with @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)