# How to define protected or private beans?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have two configs, the code goes like this.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    @Getter
    private final List<Integer> list;
}
```

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Bar {
    @Getter
    private final List<String> list;
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {

    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo(innerList()); //<-- Guess which innerList() it is. It really depends on config loading sequence
    }

    @Bean
    protected List<Integer> innerList() {
        // An ineffective "protected" bean, return type list of int
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(1);
        return result;
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class BarConfig {

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar(innerList()); 
    }

    @Bean
    protected List<String> innerList() {
        // Another "protected" bean, return type list of string
        // but have the same method name with `FooConfig.innnerList()`
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("string");
        return result;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    @Getter
    private Bar bar;


    @Autowired
    @Getter
    private Foo foo;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Init Spring context 
        // innerList() in the second config always hides the one in the first config, so BarConfig.innerList() is available here
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FooConfig.class,
                BarConfig.class, Test.class);

// Nothing changes even if disable BeanDefinitionOverriding here
//ctx.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);

        Test test = ctx.getBean(Test.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(test.getBar().getList().get(0).getClass(), String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(test.getFoo().getList().get(0).getClass(), Integer.class);// <-- Foo instance gets a wrong innerList() injected, throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

    }
}
```

The code doesn't run as expected. So my questions are...

- For bean methods, is it totally the same to have modifier `public` or `protected` once bean methods have been proxied by Spring AOP?
- Is there some way to hide beans inside the config?
- Have I triggered [Method Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-method-injection) in this case?
- Since bean methods could have the same name in a large project, is there some best practice to avoid potential conflicts(get an unexpected bean injected)?

Comment: You only have beans there is no distinction between `private`, `public` etc. So no there is no way to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would expect Spring to fail with a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` because there's multiple definitions of the `innerList` bean.

But the way you have set this up seems to work, probably because something in the `proxyBeanMethods` logic makes it work. See [When to set proxyBeanMethods to false in Springs @Configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61266792/when-to-set-proxybeanmethods-to-false-in-springs-configuration/61267087#61267087)

You cannot hide beans inside a config in Spring. Spring is intended to be an IoC container to wire applications together, I don't think hiding beans is a useful feature for that.

To avoid overlapping beans in a large project, you could use different classes to wrap things in. For your example, you would have `Foo` and `Bar` as different beans, but the `innerList` would not be a Bean.

```
@Configuration
public class BarConfig {

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar(innerList()); 
    }

    // private list just for Bar
    private List<String> innerList() {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add("string");
        return result;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class BazConfig {

    // baz really needs foo's list, so we inject Foo as a dependency
    @Bean
    public Baz baz(Foo foo) {
        return new Baz(foo.getList()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only 1 bean of `innerList` due to the fact that they have the same name. Enabling or disabling proxying won't change this (although can lead to some other interesting behavior ifyou call the methods :) ).

Comment: re. "I don't think hiding beans is a useful feature": There are other IoC lbraries that allow this. For example, Guice has PrivateModule.

Comment: Disabling proxying would make that Bar and Foo each have private innerList instances that are separate from the 2 (or 1?) beans with the name 'innerList'.

Comment: @GeertPt Proxying is so useful that I can't disable it :)

Comment: re.  "you would expect Spring to fail with a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException because there's multiple definitions of the innerList bean." 

However, Nothing changes when I call `ctx.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(false);`. I doubt is it a bug of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.