# Why use @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false) on spring configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I have found the following code snippet (code below) in the Spring Boot documentation for [Messaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.jms.receiving). Can somebody please explain me why did they use `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)` annotation on this configuration. Is it because of performance or some other magic.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyJmsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = getCustomConnectionFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new MyMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    private ConnectionFactory getCustomConnectionFactory() {
        return ...
    }

}
```

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc on Configuration.proxyBeanMethods? It clearly states the intended usage.

Comment: @MartinTheiss Nope I did not, but I see that Sergey written it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more elaborate and correct answer I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267087/3193255) (look at the example with `proxyBeanMethods = false`)

Answer (score 2):

As it comes from annotation's [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html#proxyBeanMethods()):

> Specify whether @Bean methods should get proxied in order to enforce bean lifecycle behavior, e.g. to return shared singleton bean instances even in case of direct @Bean method calls in user code. This feature requires method interception, implemented through a runtime-generated CGLIB subclass which comes with limitations such as the configuration class and its methods not being allowed to declare final.
>
> The default is true, allowing for 'inter-bean references' via direct method calls within the configuration class as well as for external calls to this configuration's @Bean methods, e.g. from another configuration class. **If this is not needed since each of this particular configuration's @Bean methods is self-contained and designed as a plain factory method for container use, switch this flag to false in order to avoid CGLIB subclass processing**.
>
> **Turning off bean method interception effectively processes @Bean methods individually like when declared on non-@Configuration classes, a.k.a. "@Bean Lite Mode" (see @Bean's javadoc)**. It is therefore behaviorally equivalent to removing the @Configuration stereotype.

there are two aspects here:

- performance (no proxy created for configuration class)
- functionality (multiple calls to a `@Bean`-annotated method return **different** objects if `proxyBeanMethods = false`)

Comment: I agree with your answer but I would say that the correct tanswer to this question lies in this answer where there is an example when to use proxyMethods = false. Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61267087/3193255

Comment: @joe_specimen nice answer indeed, I voted +1

Answer (score 1):

when you define configuration classes using `@Configuration`, Spring by default proxies all public, non-static methods of that class to enforce the semantics of bean lifecycle management, like ensuring that subsequent calls to `@Bean` methods within the same class return the same instance.
Spring offers the proxyBeanMethods attribute in `@Configuration`, which allows you to control whether Spring should proxy the methods of that configuration class. By setting `proxyBeanMethods = false`, you're essentially telling Spring not to proxy the methods, which can lead to better performance and avoid any unexpected behavior related to proxying.

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class MyJmsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory myFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = getCustomConnectionFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(new MyMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    private ConnectionFactory getCustomConnectionFactory() {
        // Implementation to obtain custom ConnectionFactory
    }
}
```

With `proxyBeanMethods = false`, Spring will treat the MyJmsConfiguration class differently, potentially improving performance and ensuring that private methods like `getCustomConnectionFactory()` are not proxied or interfered with.